# log4j.properties not working in executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

I'm using eclipse and I have placed log4j.properties in the project directory and I access it by calling

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

this works fine in Eclipse, but when I extract the project as an executable Jar and run it on another machine, I get an error saying that it can't find log4j.properties. What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### What's happening

`PropertyConfigurator.configure(String)` loads and reads a file from the file-system.  Your property file is in the project directory, which would be the "current working directory" when you run from eclipse.

Once you've packaged everything up into a jar, and deployed it - only class files and "resources" are placed into the jar.  Resources are non-java files that are under your source tree.

After you've copied the jar file to another machine, the properties file is no longer around.

#### Solutions

Since your properties file isn't a resource, you'll need to move it separately: place a copy of it on the file system (so it can be edited, updated, etc), in your current working directory of your target host/runtime environment.

Consider placing it in some common area of the file system: for example in /tmp/log4j.properties or ~/.myproject/log4j.properties.
Your code will have to be adjusted to look for it, accordingly.

#### Alternative

Copy the properties file into the root of the source tree (/src, be default).  It should then be packaged in the jar.  Load the data in the jar file as a resource: `PropertyConfigurator.configure(getClass().getResourceAsStream())`.

In this case, you can't simply edit the file to adjust your logging preferences.

Many times logic will be written to determine if a properties file is on the file system, and if not then load a default from the jar via this mechanism.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I moved the runnable jar to another machine and placed it on the Desktop and also moved log4j.properties to another machine and placed it on the Desktop. But when I run it I still get the same error as before saying the file can't be found. I'm still using the same line in my program PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties"); should I change that?

Comment: It's not the case that the directory associated with the desktop is your "current working directory" (CWD).  In Windows 7, the CWD is (by default, for desktop applications) \Users\<username>.  Under older windows it should be a directory associated with your user account (parent of "My Documents").

Comment: You can set the CWD to be used when a program is run; examine your properties and look for "Start In:".  I'm not sure that's available for an (executable) Jar file.

Comment: Also, the CWD can be shown, if you're desperate, by printing the results of `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(ABC.class.getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties"))
```

Worked me correctly, but basically you need to place `Log4j` properties file in the source code folder (next to Java Class) or you can try putting outside and give proper path in `getResourceAsStream()` method