# How to write log4j logs into eclipse Error Log View in RCP plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle

I have created an eclipse RCP Plugin for custom Logging API using  log4j.
my logging API prints log on console only. I want to print them in Eclipse Error Log View.
Please suggest how to do this in eclipse RCP plugin.

I tried ILogListner and StatusManager but couldn't succeed.
Please give some suggestions or sample code regarding this use case.

here I write custom appender and add this appender to my Logger.

```
public class VirtualConsole extends ConsoleAppender{

      @Override
        public void append(LoggingEvent event) {
            int level = IStatus.INFO;
            if (event.getLevel().equals(Level.ERROR))
                level = IStatus.ERROR;
            IStatus status = new Status(level, event.categoryName,event.getMessage().toString());
            StatusManager.getManager().handle(status, StatusManager.LOG|StatusManager.SHOW);

            //and the normal logging
            super.append(event);
      }
}
```

LoggerService.java

```
private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LoggerService.class.getName());
VirtualConsole v = new VirtualConsole();
LOGGER.addAppender(v);
```

My log4j.properties file

```
#Define root logger options
log4j.rootLogger=debug, console

#Define console appender
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
logrj.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c{1} - %m%n
```

LoggerService is an OSGI Service which is a custom logger service based on log4j.

I have a client code which consumes this LoggerService and uses log method.
whenever client invoke any LoggerService method `(i.e  loggerService.info("msg")` ) this message is logged into the console but I want to log in eclipse Error view.

I already referred [eclipse plugin development: error logging in log4j to error view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495219/eclipse-plugin-development-error-logging-in-log4j-to-error-view)

Note:- both client and service is an OSGI bundle.

Update:- 
i have on Logger Service OSGI bundle which return lo4j instance to another Client OSGI bundle and then client use this service for logging.

Comment: Did you debug if your appender is actually called when invoking the service method?

Comment: Yes it is calling, and log & status is showing in console but not in Eclipse Error log.

Comment: In ErrorLogObserver (as stated in the answer) I use the Log of the Activator (extending AbstractUIPlugin), maybe that makes a difference to using the StatusManager.

Comment: i tried with Activator.getDefaut().getLog(). but not successed.  please cloud you suggest small use case with log4j & appenders or some way to log the messages in eclipse error log.  i create logger instance in one service and use logger api in another bundle using osgi service.

Answer (score 1):

We created a library called [slf4j-plus](https://github.com/halestudio/slf4j-plus) some time ago for integrating logging into the Eclipse RCP application [hale studio](https://github.com/halestudio/hale). It offers a couple of features extending slf4j, among them also an appender that logs to the error view. You can find more information in the [documentation](https://github.com/halestudio/slf4j-plus/wiki).

So if it is an option for you to use slf4j and logback for logging you could use the library (if not, at least you use it as an example that you can follow; the actual logging to the error log happens in the [ErrorLogObserver](https://github.com/halestudio/slf4j-plus/blob/master/de.fhg.igd.slf4jplus.ui.errorlog/src/de/fhg/igd/slf4jplus/ui/errorlog/ErrorLogObserver.java)). There is a logging adapter for log4j (and Apache commons logging, etc.) to route log4j logging to slf4j, this is how you could integrate it with your current logging.

Here is a [p2 repository / update site](http://build-artifacts.wetransform.to/p2/slf4jplus/import) with the current version of the bundles in case you want to test it (does not include slf4j and logback bundles though).